# Why does this service return null when return value is not null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

Not sure why this is happening.

In the SaveRole() method when I try to hover over and see the value when debugging this line always shows null on the apiResponse variable.

```cs
var apiResponse = await RoleUiService.CreateAsync(createRoleRequest);
```

Even though it actually sets the value on _messages, after this value is set. The debugger still shows apiResponse as null.

```
if (apiResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
  NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/RoleManagement/Roles",false);
}
else
{
  _messages = apiResponse.ResponseMessages;
}
```

```cs
public class HttpService
{
  public async Task<ApiResponse<T>> HttpPostAsync<T>(string uri, object dataToSend) where T : class
  {
     var content = ToJson(dataToSend);
     var apiURL = $"{_apiBaseUrl}{uri}";

     var result = await _httpClient.PostAsync(apiURL, content);

     return await FromHttpResponseMessageAsync<T>(result);
  }
}

public class RoleUiService
{
  private readonly IHttpService _httpService;

  public RoleUiService(IHttpService httpService)
  {
     _httpService = httpService;
  }

  private async Task SaveRole()
  {
    //Debugger always shows apiResponse as null even when _messages 
    gets a value from apiResponse.ResponseMessages
   var apiResponse = await 
   
   RoleUiService.CreateAsync(createRoleRequest); 
                              
   if (apiResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
   {
      NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/RoleManagement/Roles",false);
   }
   else
   {
       _messages = apiResponse.ResponseMessages;
   }
}

//Blazor wasm component code 
public partial class CreateOrEditRole
{
  [Inject]
  public IRoleUiService RoleUiService { get; set; }

  public async Task<ApiResponse<CreateRoleResponse>> 
      CreateAsync(CreateRoleRequest createRoleRequest)
  {
    var result = await _httpService.HttpPostAsync<CreateRoleResponse> 
    (CreateRoleRequest.Route,                                                                      
    createRoleRequest);
    return result;
  }
}

//Services registered in PROGRAM.cs 

builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpService, HttpService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRoleUiService, RoleUiService>();
```

Thank you for the responses, see screen shots. Even though a value was pulled from the apiResponse and assigned to a variable the object is still reported as null.

[apiResponse object is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJCGa.png)

[apiResponse show null even though a value a was set to the var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tg85q.png)

Comment: It could help to post a screenshot. Also try querying the variable in the Immediate Window.

Comment: I Think you can try to use `F11` to let project go into next line code, And then you can check the valuel.

Comment: Updated post to include screen shots. I don't have enough points to post images directly.

Comment: In the code above, I don't see where _messages is declared, can u include the complete class?

Comment: Julio, _messages is field on razor component in a blazor wasm client. It is declared like                 private List<string>? _messages = new();

Comment: can you share the code about `RoleUiService` ?

Comment: Updated question to include service code, blazor component and Program.cs code.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible cause.

[Debugging in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fdebugger%2Ftoc.json&view=vs-2022)

[image: Screen shot from the Debugging article above]

See the picture, exactly at that point, the name has not being changed, the change will happen as soon as you advance one step and the line where the name variable is assigned is no longer highlighted.

In this article, just bellow this picture it says:

> Hover over the name variable to see its current value, which is an empty string.

Comment: The odd part in my question is a value is set from the object but the parent object still is reported as null!